# What does "this" refer to (when iterating through a collection)

Tags: backbone.js, foreach, underscore.js

I'm trying to reach a collection instance with the `this` keyword, when iterating through its models. Here is my test code:

```
myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: 'model.com'
});    

myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: myModel,
    url: 'collection.com',

    iterateAll: function(){
        this.each(function(item){
             console.log(this.url);
             console.log(item.url);
        });
    }
});

mod = new myModel();
col = new myCollection(mod);

col.iterateAll();
```

This code outputs:

```
undefined
model.com
```

How can I reference the collection correctly when using `this.url`? I want the output to read `collection.com` not `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is pretty weird in JavaScript.

```
iterateAll: function() {
    var self = this; // _this is also common
    this.each(function(item) {
         console.log(self.url);
         console.log(item.url);
    });
}
```

Basically, JavaScript doesn't formally distinguish between *methods* and *functions*. As a result, every function invocation -- even simple anonymous callbacks like these -- gets its own `this` value. But this very frequently isn't...what anyone wants ever. So you can hold onto the "useful" value of `this` in a temporary variable and reference it in the callback.

This is so common that it's a feature of [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) via the `=>` syntax, and it's going to be a feature of ES6. Until then...temp variables are we've got.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
...
iterateAll: function(){
    var me = this;
    me.each(function(item){
         console.log(me.url);
         console.log(item.url);
    });
}
...
```

More info on `this` scope. http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/